# Progress Circle Not Going Around Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cant seem to get the progress circle around all three images. Here is a JSFiddle of the problem. Please help!

http://jsfiddle.net/ror37gjk/60/

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper>#bar, #bar2, #bar3,
.wrapper>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper>img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4%;
}

.wrapper>img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'

});
circle.animate(1);

var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar2', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'

});
circle.animate(1);

var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar3', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'

});
circle.animate(1);
```

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'
});

circle.animate(1);

var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar2', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'
});

circle.animate(1);

var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar3', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'
});

circle.animate(1);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper > #bar,
#bar2,
#bar3 {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper > #bar,
#bar2,
#bar3,
.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/master/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="bar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/391FcV0.png" /></div>
  <div id="bar2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/NtqQEKF.png" /></div>
  <div id="bar3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/NGROIlB.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it in my css, html, and javascript. But when I open the html file its not animating. I'm pretty sure i have my javascript linked up right. I don't know whats going on.

Comment: that's a completely different story... have you checked for errors in the console?